# For a simple pendulum does the size of bob need to be small w.r.t. the string to be considered as harmonic oscillator?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, oscillators, approximations

if a simple pendulum has a bob with radius comparable to a string can it still be considered as shm given the amplitude is small?

Comment: The derivation assumed the angle is small so that you only need to solve a few Taylor expansion terms instead of the full differential equation

Comment: Could you explain why you are a little confused? It would be good to add this to your question. I suspect that the downvote for your question and for 3 of the answers is because the question doesn't – as it stands – show any "research effort" or reveal any of your thoughts about it.

Comment: Why do you think the bob needs to be small (as implied by the title of your post). Are you assuming the answer is A or C? The answer is actually B, regardless of what your answer sheet says.

Comment: I'd guess that the expected answer is D. Any shape of pendulum will oscillate with SHM if the amplitude is limitingly small. 10°, though, is controversial.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the bob is too big we won't be able to consider it as a punctual particle where gravity and the cable act (the tangential forces won't exactly be tangential anymore for all points of the bob).

Instead, the bob will have its own rotation respect to the link with the cable, which won't be negligible anymore and will change the dynamics of the energy through that, kinematic-potential will be transferred slower or quicker, deviating the movement exactly from an exact harmonic oscillation.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that in a Physics context I'd call a non-rigid system that deforms as it moves a pendulum.

Comment: A spherical bob will act as if the mass if concentrated at the center. You seem to be trying to justify OPs assumption (in the title his post) that the answer is A or C. It is not.

Answer (score 1):

[The question has been radically changed since this answer was written.]

(i) is not a requirement for simple harmonic motion. Provided that the amplitude is very small, a rigid pendulum of any shape (for example a sphere on a rod) will perform simple harmonic motion of period
$$T=2\pi \sqrt {\frac{I}{mgh}}$$
in which $I$ is the moment of inertia of the pendulum about the pivot, $m$ is the pendulum's mass and $h$ is the distance from its centre of mass to the pivot.

We show this by equating the torque about the pivot due to the centre of mass being displaced through a small angle from its equilibrium position (directly below the pivot) to the moment of inertia multiplied by the angular acceleration.

Note that for a *simple* pendulum (to which a small sphere on a light thread approximates) of length $l$, $h=l$ and $I=ml^2$, giving a very familiar formula for $T$ !

Comment: Why the downvote? Am I not answering the question? Do you think that the answer is wrong?

Answer (score -1):

it is perhaps easiest to consider it as circular motion with the external torque $\tau$ producing an angular acceleration $\alpha$ with $\tau = I_{\rm pivot}\alpha$.

$I_{\rm pivot}$ is the moment of inertia of the bob about the pivot and by the parallel axes theorem, is equal to the moment of inertia of the bob about its centre of mass $I_{\rm com}$ plus the moment inertia of inertia of the bob as though it is a point mass about the pivot $I_{\rm point,pivot}$.

When deriving the simple pendulum formula the assumption is made that $I_{\rm com}\ll  I_{\rm point,pivot}$ which is true if the size of the bob is much less than the length of the string.

Comment: -1 Why a downvote for all? It would help if down votes had an explanation attached to them.

Comment: I'm sure we both suspect that we're being punished for answering a homework-like question. But downvotes signify "This answer is not useful" and I'd have thought that our answers ARE useful – certainly to the question-asker  and probably to a few other readers. Anyway, it would, as you say, be an enormous help to everyone if downvoters gave reasons.